# Class constructor MongoStore cannot be invoked without 'new' (Express-NodeJs)Backend

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I m creating react-auth . Firstly I created server side. I need to connect mongodb but i didnt manage.

`const session = require('express-session')` const Mongostore = require('connect-mongo')(session)
``const cors = require('cors')

`app.use(session({`  secret: 'secret',
`store: new Mongostore({`   mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection
`}),`  resave: true,
`saveUninitialized: true` }))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had a similar issue while working on replit. My solution was to downgrade connect-mongo's version from 4 to 3.

```
npm uninstall connect-mongo
npm i connect-mongo@3
```

From this user's post:
https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/advanced-node-and-express-error/450979/3

Comment: Thanks, that fixed my issue. I also could not get new syntax `store: MongoStore.create({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })` to work by reusing an existing connection to a replica set and with required authentication

Answer (score 12):

For those who want to the latest version of connect-mongo, the new syntax involves removing the parameter session from the require call and not using new any more but a method .create.

Here is what the documentation recommends:

```
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo');

app.use(session({
  secret: 'foo',
  store: MongoStore.create(options)
}));
```

Basic usage would be:

```
app.use(session({
  store: MongoStore.create({ mongoUrl: 'mongodb://localhost/test-app' })
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
      const session=require("express-session");
  const MongoStore=require("connect-mongo");
//*****************
  app.use(session({
   secret:"secret",
   cookie:{maxAge:60000},
   resave:false,
   saveUninitialized:false,
   store:MongoStore.create({mongoUrl:process.env.MONGO_URI}),
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same Error, What i did was to *npm i connect-mongodb-session*

```
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongodb-session)(session)
```

I then created a middleware by session

```
    app.use(
      session({
      secret: 'keyboard cat',
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: process.env.MONGO_URI }),
  })
);
```

Instead of coding my URI directly, i instead loaded it from the *.env file* with *process.env.MONGO_URI*

Answer (score 0):

Please make the following changes on your code, from:

```
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
```

Use, instead:

```
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')
```

And in the session object options use:

```
store: MongoStore.create({ mongoUrl: process.env.CONNECTIONSTRING })
```

process.env.CONNECTIONSTRING is the link provided by mongodb that you may store in the .env

I tried downgrading the mongo-connect version as suggested above but found it more reliable to keep it up to date with current version and using the new method create with different key name, following the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongo#connection-to-mongodb) guidelines

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To fix it, I updated the code to the following:

```js
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo'); 
app.use(session({
  secret: 'sessionKey', 
  resave: true, 
  saveUninitialized: false, 
  store: new MongoStore({
      mongoUrl: 'mongodb://127.0.0.1/database_name', 
  })
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
app.use(session({
  name: 'nameOfProject',
  secret: 'put',
  saveUninitialized: false,
  resave: false,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 100 * 60 * 1000, // 100 minutes in milliseconds
  },
  store: new MongoStore({
    mongoUrl:'mongodb://127.0.0.1/db_name', //add mongo URL here
    mongooseConnection:db,
    autoRemove:'disabled'
  },
  function(err) {
    console.log(err || "connection to mongodb is ok");
  })
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instead for latest version of `mongo-connect`

```js
     const MongoStore = require("connect-mongo")
     const dbString = "mongodb://localhost:27017/db_name"

     const sessionStore = MongoStore.create({
     mongoUrl: dbString,
     collectionName: 'session'
     })

     app.use(session({
     secret: "pj",
     resave: false,
     saveUninitialized: true,
     store: sessionStore,
     cookie: {
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 //Equals 24 hours
     }
     }))
```