# I want to store session using mongo store, but this gives me the following error "Class constructor MongoStore cannot be invoked without 'new'"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I searched stack overflow and found that there's been some change in the syntax. But trying that code only worsened the situation. Please help me write the correct code.

Here is my code

```
app.use(
  session({
    name: "MajorProject",
    secret: "blahsomething",
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 100,
    },

    store: new MongoStore(
      {
        mongooseConnection: db,
        autoRemove: "disabled",
      },
      (error) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
          return;
        }
        console.log("Connected-mongodb setup success");
      }
    ),
  })
);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Class constructor MongoStore cannot be invoked without 'new' (Express-NodeJs)Backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67309712/class-constructor-mongostore-cannot-be-invoked-without-new-express-nodejsbac)

Comment: Not exactly, this post shows two solutions, first one is to downgrade the nodejs version, but i really can't do that. The second answer seems to be the one, but can you tell me what exactly do we have to put inside  mongoUrl: